# State is not working as expected after navigating back to previous page in browser in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-state-management

I am developing a React + Redux web application. I am having a problem with the state management.

I have a component called `EditEventComponent` with the following definition.

```
class EditEventComponent extends React.Component{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        //curator/event/{event_id}/details
        this.fetchEvent = this.fetchEvent.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        this.fetchEvent();
    }

    fetchEvent()
    {
        this.props.startFetchingEvent();
        let path = "curator/event/" + this.props.match.params.id + "/details";
        getHttpClient().get(path)
        .then((response) => {
            this.props.completeFetchingEvent(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.props.errorFetchingEvent();
        });
    }

    render()
    {
        let props = this.props;
        return (<EventFormComponent {...props} />)

    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state)
{
    return {
        submittingForm : state.editEvent.submittingForm,
        formErrors : state.editEvent.formErrors,
        event: state.editEvent.event,
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch)
{
    return bindActionCreators({
        startFetchingEvent: EditEventActions.startFetchingEvent,
        completeFetchingEvent : EditEventActions.completeFetchingEvent,
        errorFetchingEvent: EditEventActions.errorFetchingEvent,
        startFormSubmission: EditEventActions.startFormSubmission,
        completeFormSubmission : EditEventActions.completeFormSubmission,
        errorFormSubmission: EditEventActions.errorFormSubmission,
        changeInputField : EditEventActions.changeInputfield
    }, dispatch);
}

const enhance = compose(withWidth(), withStyles(themeStyles, { withTheme: true }), connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps))
export default enhance(EditEventComponent);
```

As you can see, it is loading the event asynchronously from the server. Then pass the event value to the EventFormComponent.

This is the definition of the EventComponent.

```
class EventFormComponent extends React.Component{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.submitCreateEventForm = this.submitCreateEventForm.bind(this);
        this.onInputValueChange = this.onInputValueChange.bind(this);
        this.getServerFormatDateTime = this.getServerFormatDateTime.bind(this);
        this.onCoverPhotoFileValueChange = this.onCoverPhotoFileValueChange.bind(this);
        this.validateForm = this.validateForm.bind(this);
        this.sendUpdateEventRequest = this.sendUpdateEventRequest.bind(this);
        this.renderEventInputField = this.renderEventInputField.bind(this);
        this.state = { 
            startdatetime: null ,
            enddatetime: null ,
            coverPhotoFile: null,
            name: "",
            location: "",
            description: "",
            latitude: "",
            longitude: "",
            organizers: "",
            attendees: ""
        }
        this.isEditing = this.props.event == null;
    }



    setStartDateTime = (dateTime) => this.setState({ startdatetime: dateTime })

    setEndDateTime = (dateTime) => this.setState({ enddatetime: dateTime })

    onInputValueChange(e)
    {
        alert(this.isEditing)
        switch(e.target.name)
        {
            case "name":
            this.setState({ name:  e.target.value })
            break;

            case "location":
            this.setState({ location:  e.target.value })
            break;

            case "description":
            this.setState({ description:  e.target.value })
            break;

            case "latitude":
            this.setState({ latitude:  e.target.value })
            break;

            case "longitude":
            this.setState({ longitude:  e.target.value })
            break;

            case "organizers":
            this.setState({ organizers:  e.target.value })
            break;

            case  "attendees":
            this.setState({ attendees:  e.target.value })
            break;
        }
        if(this.isEditing)
        {

            this.props.changeInputField({ field: e.target.name, value: e.target.value });
        }
    }

    submitCreateEventForm(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(this.validateForm())
        {
            this.sendUpdateEventRequest();
        }

    }

    sendUpdateEventRequest()
    {
        let startDateTime = this.getServerFormatDateTime(String(this.state.startdatetime));
        let endDateTime = this.getServerFormatDateTime(String(this.state.enddatetime));
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("cover_photo_file", this.state.coverPhotoFile);
        formData.append("name", this.state.name);
        formData.append("location", this.state.location);
        formData.append("latitude", this.state.latitude);
        formData.append("longitude", this.state.longitude);
        formData.append("description", this.state.description);
        formData.append("attendee_emails",  this.state.attendees);
        formData.append("organizer_emails", this.state.organizers);
        formData.append('start_date',startDateTime.date);
        formData.append('start_time', startDateTime.time);
        formData.append('end_date', endDateTime.date);
        formData.append("end_time", endDateTime.time);
        formData.append('is_csv', true);

        let path  = "";
        if(this.isEditing)
        {
            formData.append('id', this.props.event.id);
            path = "event/post";
        }
        else
        {
            path = "event/update";
        }

        this.props.startFormSubmission();
        getHttpClient("multipart/form-data")
        .post("event/post", formData)
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.data.success)
            {
                this.props.completeFormSubmission();
                this.props.history.push("/events");
            }
            else
            {
                this.props.errorFormSubmission(response.data.errors);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.props.errorFormSubmission([ "Internal error thrown." ])
        })
    }

    validateForm()
    {

        if(this.state.name == null || this.state.name.trim()=="")
        {
            this.props.errorFormSubmission([ "Name is required" ]);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    onCoverPhotoFileValueChange(e)
    {
        this.setState({ coverPhotoFile: e.target.files[0] });
    }

    getServerFormatDateTime(dateTime)
    {
        if(dateTime!==null && dateTime!=="")
        {
            let segs = dateTime.split(" ");
            let date = segs[1] + "/" + segs[2] + "/" + segs[3];
            let time = segs[4];
            return { date: date, time: time }
        }
        else
        {
            return { date: null, time: null };
        }
    }

    renderEventInputField(fieldName)
    {
        if(this.isEditing && this.props.event)
        {
            if(this.props.event[fieldName])
            {
                return this.props.event[fieldName];
            }
            else
            {
                return '';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    render()
    {
        let formLoadingView = null;
        if(this.props.submittingForm)
        {
            formLoadingView = <div>Processing request....</div>
        }


        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
            <div className={scss['page-container']}>
            <Grid
            spacing={16}
            container>
                <Grid item md={12}>
                    <Card>
                    <CardContent>
                        <form onSubmit={this.submitCreateEventForm}>
                        {this.props.formErrors.map((item, index)=> {
                            return <div key={index}>{item}</div>
                        })}
                        <div>
                            <label>Cover photo</label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="file" onChange={this.onCoverPhotoFileValueChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <TextField
                            onChange={this.onInputValueChange}
                            className={scss['form-control']}
                            name="name"
                            label="Name"
                            value={this.props.event && this.props.event.name? this.props.event.name: ""} />
                        </div>
                        <div>  
                            <TextField
                            onChange={this.onInputValueChange}
                            className={scss['form-control']}
                            name="location"
                            label="Location"
                            value={this.props.event && this.props.event.location? this.props.event.location: ""} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <TextField
                            onChange={this.onInputValueChange}
                            className={scss['form-control']}
                            name="latitude"
                            label="Latitude"
                            value={this.props.event && this.props.event.latitude? this.props.event.latitude: ""} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <TextField
                            onChange={this.onInputValueChange}
                            className={scss['form-control']}
                            name="longitude"
                            label="Longitude"
                            value={this.props.event && this.props.event.longitude? this.props.event.longitude: ""} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <TextField
                            onChange={this.onInputValueChange}
                            className={scss['form-control']}
                            name="attendees"
                            label="Attendees (Emails)"
                            value={this.props.event && this.props.event.attendee_emails? this.props.event.attendee_emails: ""} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <TextField
                            onChange={this.onInputValueChange}
                            className={scss['form-control']}
                            name="organizers"
                            label="Organizers (Emails)"
                            value={this.props.event && this.props.event.organizer_emails? this.props.event.organizer_emails: ""} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <TextField
                            onChange={this.onInputValueChange}
                            className={scss['form-control']}
                            name="description"
                            label="Description"
                            value={this.props.event && this.props.event.description? this.props.event.description: ""} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <div className={scss['form-control']}>
                        <DateTimePicker 
                            fullWidth
                            format='MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A'
                            hintText="Start date & time"
                            onChange={this.setStartDateTime}
                            value={this.props.event && this.props.event.start_date_time? this.props.event.start_date_time: ""}
                            DatePicker={DatePickerDialog}
                            TimePicker={TimePickerDialog}
                            />
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <div className={scss['form-control']}>
                        <DateTimePicker 
                            fullWidth
                            format='MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A'
                            hintText="End date & time"
                            onChange={this.setEndDateTime}
                            value={this.props.event && this.props.event.end_date_time? this.props.event.end_date_time: ""}
                            DatePicker={DatePickerDialog}
                            TimePicker={TimePickerDialog}
                            />
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>

                        </div>
                        <div>
                        {formLoadingView}
                        <Grid>
                        <Button disabled={this.props.submittingForm} type="submit" color="primary" variant="raised">Save</Button>
                        </Grid>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </CardContent>
                    </Card>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
    }

}

export default EventFormComponent;
```

Note the this.isEditing property in the constructor.

Now, what I am doing is there is page that display the list of events which uses EventListComponent. From that page, if a user click on an event widget, user is redirect to the edit page (EditEventComponent). I run the app, then click on a event widget and which is redirect to the edit page.

The this.isEditing property becomes true as expected as well since the event is not null. Then, I go back to the previous page (EventListComponent) clicking on the previous button in the browser. Then I choose an event widget again to edit. Then when I click the edit page is displayed for the second time, the isEditing field is no longer true event if the event data are loaded.

The event is not null. But the isEditing property is false. I cannot think of a solution. I don't know why as well. I think it happens when I click the "go back" button in browser and the choose an item to edit again which will redirect the user to the edit page back. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: the code and description seem to contradict in this line.
"The this.isEditing property becomes true as expected as well since the event is not null"
`this.isEditing = this.props.event == null;`
`this.isEditing` should be `true` if `this.props.event` is `null`. later on: "The event is not null. But the isEditing property is false." when in fact the code in the constructor supports this statement.